# Is there a way to remove the payment method tab on the Payment element?

Tags: stripe-payments

I set up my stripe payment and everything works well, but I have one issue with my payment Element, I want to remove the payment options tab  all together, so the first element that shows is the card number input and nothing above it, not even the "Card" choice.

CardElement isn't a solution because it doesn't take some of the other info I want.

[image: id="payment-element"]

I hope this was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to accept card payments with the Payment Element (and not accept any other payment methods), you can explicitly pass in `payment_method_types : ['card']` when creating the PaymentIntent or SetupIntent.